# Exporting png in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with displaying values ​​in my graph, when I downloading, the values middle line is displayed, but the columns value is not.
I want to display the value of the columns and not the average. Help me please!

```
  exporting: {
            sourceWidth: 1920,
            sourceHeight: 600,
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: ['downloadPNG']
                }
            },
            chartOptions: {
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your code on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: of course, https://jsfiddle.net/alexserden/wq6j0tnp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the simple changes from:

```
chartOptions: {
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to:

```
chartOptions: {
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

should be enough to achieve your requirement. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r9yn0wx5/